# using javascript modulus to add class to every third item but dont want this to be applied to first 0

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add last to every `i` value that divides perfectly by 3, but I don't want index 0 to be one of them.  Can anyone tell me how I can use modulus on every 3rd item except the first?

```
((i%3==0) ? 'last' : '');
```

Comment: Just check that `i != 0` as well as `i%3 == 0`.

Comment: Just a note: if you are going to use this only for styling, take a look at CSS selectors. For example `li:nth-child(3n)` will apply a style to every 3 elements (it starts counting from 1).

Comment: @AlexStack - Exactly.. No need to loop with the index or any explicit conditions in that case

Comment: If you are going to use that for a selector, then make sure you check the what browsers you need to be compatible with. I am almost positive that is a CSS3 selector and it doesn't have support on all browsers (IE8).

Comment: yeah i need this for ie7 + 8 so I need to go with this

Comment: For browsers that don't support CSS3 you can use Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (i!=0 && i % 3 == 0) ...
```

Sometimes instead of trying to find a inclusive solution for your edge case, just be explicit and say you don't want to include 0.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
if(i > 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
    // stuff ...
}
```

If all you need to do is apply a CSS class to all 3rd elements excluding the first one, you should be able to just do:

```
$('.yourClass:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('newClass');​
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/uuBzD/

If counting starts at index `0`, this will apply the class to elements `3`, `6`, `9` and so on..

Comment: People should make it a point to explain why they downvoted. Otherwise its just not right.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound too simple but if it is a `for` loop, you can start counting from 1 and it will not be necessary to have the check in every iteration (slightly better performance):

```
for ( var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  arr[i].className = i % 3 ? "" : "last";
}
```

If you don't need to assign the `className` for the elements that `i %3` is not `0` then you can improve the performance slightly more by using an `if`:

```
for ( var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if ( !( i % 3 ) ) {
    arr[i].className = "last";
  }
}
```

And of course if you have to start counting from 0, you can go with this loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if ( !( i % 3 ) && ( i ) ) {
    arr[i].className = "last";
  }
}
```

The reason `i!==0` condition is put after `i % 3` is because the first condition is more common and it needs to be checked on almost all iterations so the performance will be even better than blindly checking `i!==0` in every iteration.

Anyway, to shortly answer it in your own coding style:

```
(i%3==0 && i ? 'last' : '');
```

Comment: People should make it a point to explain why they downvoted. Otherwise its just not right.

Comment: exactly. it's so mean to downvote an answer instead of giving feedback. We are here to learn from each other.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some of the posted answers, I found the easiest solution was to add 1 to the index to make the calculation non-zero based:

```
var isThirdIteration = (i + 1) % 3 === 0;
```